# Issue regarding javascript function not firing on hover of div

Tags: javascript, css-selectors

I have a use case whereby i know that all the divs i am interested in will have the word 'tabz' in them but have yet to find a way to fire my jquery when a user clicks on a div with such an id.

```
$('div[id=*"tabz"]').on("click", function()
{
 alert(event.target.id);
});
```

This is what i have however the alert never fires.

When I replace the method with :

```
   $('div').on("click", function()
  {
    alert(event.target.id);
  });
```

it will give me the following:

## tabz91

So i know there are divs that meet my selector but it I am unsure as to why the alert is not firing.

Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax is simply

> $('div[id*="tabz"]')

(the = and the * are inverted in your example).

You may use

> $('div[id$="tabz"]')

if the id attribute ends with your pattern.

Comment: Hi thankyou for your response but that does not seem to have worked for some odd reason

Comment: Thankyou, for some reason my code does not pick up on this however when using jfiddle it works as does it work if i do $('div') instead of the selector so i am unsure what quirk i am up against. Nonetheless this was the answer to the question

Answer (score 2):

```
$('div[id*="tabz"]').on("click", function()
{
 alert(event.target.id);
});
```

It's a typo, `*` and `=` inverted. See this example : http://jsfiddle.net/Xcn6N/

Answer (score 2):

try instead of `=*` it is `*=`

```
$('div[id*="tabz"]').on("click", function() {
 alert(event.target.id);
});
```

For Further Assistance on Selectors in jQuery see this page

## [jQuery Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)